# c# wrapping a Task into a another Task

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to use inter process communication to send from one instance of my program its content to the other instance. The code I have under here is working but it makes the first instance freeze and only continues running when the second instansce is created and the data is passed back.I suspect its because messaging_server0() is not a async task. How would one approach this problem. Is there a way to make messaging_server0 async? or am I missing something?

main loop contains this piece of code

```
var makeTask = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => pipe_server.messaging_server0());

if (makeTask.Result != null) { 
    dataGrid_logic.DataGridLoadTarget(makeTask.Result);
}
```

and on the other side I have messaging_server0

```
public static string  messaging_server0()
{
    using (var messagebus1 = new TinyMessageBus("ExampleChannel"))
    {
        string ret = null;

        messagebus1.MessageReceived += (sender, e) => ret = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message);

        while (true)
        {
            if (ret != null)
            {
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The method names are going to be refactored.

Comment: You are starting the messaging task asynchronously but are immediately checking for its `Result`, for which it has no choice but to block the calling thread and wait for the task to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest following approach:

```
    public static async Task<string> messaging_server0()
    {
        using (var messagebus1 = new TinyMessageBus("ExampleChannel"))

        {
            var taskCompletition = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

            messagebus1.MessageReceived +=
                (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var ret = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message);
                    taskCompletition.TrySetResult(ret);
                };

            return await taskCompletition.Task;
        }
    }
```

Obviously you would need to add some error handling, time outs if needed etc.

Comment: Would not the messagebus get disposed upon returning from this method.

Comment: I still get the same result, the main app freezes until the second instance starts.  I think I need to edit the main loop that calls the method or? http://i.imgur.com/rj8CSCm.png

Comment: @Nkosi good point, I edited the answer to avoid disposing the `TinyMessageBus` after we go out of this method. Obviously it's one of possible approached, the other being to keep a reference to the `TinyMessageBus` for as long as needed.

Comment: @BoKKeR please add code snippets by editing your question as it's hard to tell from you screen-shot code snippet. For sure you shouldn't access Task results via `Wait` or `Result` because it causes the thread to block which can be the main reason why you app freezes.

Comment: @alekkowalczyk your edit was not accurate. The method should return a task. The using statement is what needs to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

with the help of alek kowalczyk and some digging I came up with this code

```
    private async void xxx()
    {
        var makeTask = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => pipe_server.messaging_server());

        await pipe_server.messaging_server();
        {
            dataGrid_logic.DataGridLoadTarget(makeTask.Result);

        }
    }
```

plus the snippet he posted. 
This works perfectly. thanks